# Can I use Service Principal to authenticate an application that is not hosted in Azure using role-based access control?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I've created an event hub that I want to call from an app hosted outside of Azure. Can I create a service principal in AAD and use it for authentication of the non-Azure hosted application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it doesnt matter if the application is hosted in Azure or not, service principal is used to auth, it doesnt check where you are hosting the app.

But i dont think you can use service principal to talk to event hub, you will need to use connection string

Comment: Role based access control is a preview feature for event hubs currently that allows me to assign a role to a service principal. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: interesting, got a link for that?

Comment: Here's one at least: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-role-based-access-control